# Magento + PayPal Sandbox

Tags: magento, paypal-sandbox

So, recently PayPal switched from sandbox.paypal to developer.paypal interface. It is still in beta mode, so it's not working perfectly, and on the other hand sandbox is practically disabled, you can not register nor login with old credentials.

So, when trying to make a test system in Magento, I create one seller account and one buyer account in new developer.paypal interface, but when I try to make a purchase it keeps showing me the wrong login/pass error (I enter the seller account e-mail and password).

Before all this I remember I had to be logged in the sandbox.paypal with my main sandbox account for this to work, but now login to sandbox is not possible any more, and login to developer doesn't help.

Anyone had similar issues? I tried anywhere to find any clue for solution, but no luck, and I don't waiting for PayPal to complete their test environment is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't had the same issue however have you imported your old accounts? That way you can use the same test email addresses and passwords as before.

- Log into https://developer.paypal.com
- Click Applications
- Click Sandbox accounts
- Click "Import data"
- Enter your email address and password for the old developer account.

All settings for the prior accounts should be imported as well. Sandbox.paypal.com is still accessible too, you do need to be logged into your developer account to access it which is the same condition as before.

If you continue receiving a password error trying resetting the password to the accounts by following the steps below:

- Log into https://developer.paypal.com
- Click Applications
- Click Sandbox accounts
- Expand the account in question
- Click "Profile"
- Click "Change Password"

Lastly, you'll also want to delete all developer.paypal.com cookies and cache before using the beta environment. If you do not, you'll see the error message below:

"This Sandbox email address is not available. Please enter another email address."

Let me know if you continue to receive errors.

Comment: thank you so much! clearing the cache and cookies solved it, weird stuff :)